# is there a way to prevent mySQL results from the same user_id being sequential?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products like this:

`product_name | product_id | user_id`

I don't have a lot of sorting options on the table, but I'd like to make it so that products from the same `user_id` don't come right one after the other, like:

```
product from 21
product from 21
product from 21
product from 17
product from 17
product from 17
product from 53
product from 53
product from 53
```

Is there any easy way for mySQL to randomise it so that it shows like this?

```
product from 21
product from 53
product from 17
product from 21
product from 17
product from 53
product from 21
product from 17
product from 53
```

I know that you can randomise results returned, but there's a problem if there are multiple pages, then results may be repeated.

So, is there any easy way to have mySQL know `hey, you can't show 2 results of user 21 together` ?

Comment: you can order by random or use variables, but your results will vary and may not always please

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way. You could `order by rand()` but there's no guarantee that two of the same wouldn't appear next to each other. You could order by something else (productid or product name) but you still have the same problem. The other option would be to write a custom sorting function in PHP (or whatever language you're using) but again it wouldn't exactly be straight forward nor efficient.

Comment: That's an interesting thought! `order by rand()` would keep the results random on that page, but still away from the next page. Simple, genius ..

Comment: Hmmm crap, that's not working too spread across pages :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is `... ORDER BY rand()`.    To me, this is somewhat sloppy, because you will get different results every time the query is run, but it does work.  One way to mix up the order is to combine fields to make a simple hash.  For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `product_id` * `user_id`
```

This way, the results are always the same if the query is run multiple times but you get a quasi-random order for each query.  This has the added benefit of allowing you to paginate your results, because the order is the same for every query no matter what `LIMIT` is.  You can try adding fields, subtracting fields, or even combining multiple operations.

Another way to add even more quasi-randomness is to perform string functions on the product name.  For example, search for the location of the first 'b' in the product name and add it to the product/user hash:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `product_id` * `user_id` + INSTR(`product_name`, 'b')
```

Using string functions is quite a bit more 'expensive' than multiplication, but if the first query doesn't mix up the results enough, this probably would.